# Random number generation in python

Tags: python, random, cryptography

Is this a valid way to generate `n` random bytes that are cryptographically random?

```
def cryptographically_secure_random_bytes(n):
    return ''.join(chr(random.SystemRandom().randint(0,256)) for _ in range(n))
```

I know `random.SystemRandom()` is the same as `os.urandom()`, and I know that `os.urandom()` is definitely a cryptographically secure way of generating random numbers.

However, the `chr(random.SystemRandom().randint(0,256))` part throws me off a bit. Since `chr()` doesn't support unicode, I'm assuming that this function is discarding some characters that would otherwise be produced by `random.SystemRandom()`.

I'm not sure what to think of `randint(0,256)` either, since that is the size of a byte.

Comment: I think that randint's upper bound is inclusive. So your randint could technically be more than one byte if it returns 256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[random.randint(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.randint)

> Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for
>   randrange(a, b+1).

So it is inclusive you could get something bigger than a byte.

Comment: In other words, the answer is: NO!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`secret`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html?#module-secrets) module!

From the docs:

*The `secrets` module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.*

*In particularly, `secret`s should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the `random` module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.*

Comment: I would certainly use that if I were writing this code, however, this question is related to code that isn't mine.

Comment: Also, SystemRandom is *not* the default PRNG in the random module.